# I need to include @JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS) annotation at generated pojo either class level or field level using swagger code generator

Tags: spring-boot, maven, swagger-codegen

I need to add `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)` annotation at generated POJO class like below.

Here is the Swagger code generator maven plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
          <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
<configOptions>                <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
</configOptions>
</plugin>
```

And here is my pojo

```
@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)
public class Pet {
@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name = null;
}
```

Please check and help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

We need to use Open API code generator version 6.x tool instead of swagger code generator . This will fix the problem